# how do i send client secret to cognito for signin

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito

After a user is authenticated by a node.js backend API a jwt token is sent back to the UI.  The client id is in the jwt token and I have not found any configuration in AWS that will allow me to remove it from the jwt token.  Since the client is available in the jwt a user can call the

```
curl -X POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ -H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'x-amz-target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.SignUp' -d '{"ClientId":"<YOUR APP CLIENT ID>","Username":"<YOUR EMAIL ID>","Password":"<YOUR PASSWORD>","UserAttributes":[{"Name":"email","Value":"<YOUR EMAIL ID>"}],"ValidationData":null}'
```

to sign up users.

I want to prevent this.  One solution is to add client secret.  However, I do not see any way to pass the client secret from the node.js backend to cognito for the signin (authentication). Here is my sample code.

```
(async () => {
    const c1 = {
        "idpType": "cognito",
        "userPoolId": "us-east-xxxxxxxx",
        "clientId": "6k28h",
        "clientIdSecret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "region": "us-east-2"
    };
    const cognitoConfig = c1;
    const aws = require('aws-amplify');revent users from being able to sign up

    const Amplify = aws.Amplify;
    const Auth = aws.Auth;

    Amplify.configure({
        Auth: {
            // REQUIRED - Amazon Cognito Region
            region: cognitoConfig.region,
            userPoolId: cognitoConfig.userPoolId,
            userPoolWebClientId: cognitoConfig.clientId
        }
    });

    try {
        const user = await Auth.signIn('user@corp.com', 'xxxxxx@xxx');
        console.log(user)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('error signing in', error);
    }
})();
```

error signing in NotAuthorizedException: Client 6k28h is configured for secret but secret was not received
at /home/user/aws-cognito/node_modules/@aws-amplify/auth/node_modules/amazon-cognito-identity-js/lib/Client.js:153:19
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
code: 'NotAuthorizedException'
}

Comment: The client ID is not something that is kept secret. Why are you trying to remove it from the token?

Comment: @AndrewGilis The client id can be used to send signup request to the user pool through curl -X POST https://cognito-idp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/ -H 'Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'x-amz-target: AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.SignUp' -d '{"ClientId":"<YOUR APP CLIENT ID>","Username":"<YOUR EMAIL ID>","Password":"<YOUR PASSWORD>","UserAttributes":[{"Name":"email","Value":"<YOUR EMAIL ID>"}],"ValidationData":null}'.  So, I am looking for ways to prevent this.

Comment: Then disable self-signup in the userpool configuration...